# How to get the missing DLL name after when GetLastError() returns ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, winapi

My application loads a DLL using [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suppressing the standard critical-error-handler message box. When `LoadLibrary()` fails and [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns [ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (0x7E) I'd like to retrieve the missing DLL name. This error code is set not only when the requested DLL is missing, **but also when any DLL it depends on is missing**.

It's worth noting that the standard message box (which is suppressed) displays the correct missing DLL name, and the question is how can I get it within the code.

Thanks

Comment: No, the name doesn't get stored anywhere.  The loader message box that you disabled with SetErrorMode is all there is.

Comment: Interesting question, but what do you plan on doing with this information? If you want to use it for debugging, use a tool like dependency walker. If it's for the end user, I wonder how useful this information would be anyway.

Comment: Its not exactly for debugging. The application is a tiny web server and the DLL it's trying to load are configuration parameters. This error indicates a faulty configuration file. The standard message box pops up on the server which is inaccessible to the user running a web browser so it needs to be suppressed. What I wanted to do is to send the user the best error message I can including the exact name of the missing DLL. Its probably true I can add code that retraces the dependencies and finds out exactly which DLL is missing, but I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @HansPassant do you got any reference on this? I don't get it. The dialog is a program. it must access this information somehow. It sounds like there *must* be a way to do it programmatically. to lack a way to get the name would mean the dialog remembers the name from load-time but it can't if it's a dependency dll, so I think there must be a way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's an easy way of getting the missing DLL's name. But you can probably find it by stepping through LoadLibrary() in the debugger and seeing which function fails with what filename in the parameters. depends.exe can also show the dependencies.

Also, it might worth a try firing up the process monitor and using appropriate filters see what I/O errors there are in your process and for what files.

Comment: If you turn on loader snaps, then the loader will print diagnostic information to the debugger. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx

Comment: this seems to be option for humans. instead of programs. if [s]he suppresses the dialog [s]he could just as well display it for the debugging moment. but if [s]he wants to do this programmatically or from a script, this is where re-enabling the dialog wouldn't help. so I assume the question is about programmatical handling of this. which [s]he seems to confirm in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661283/how-to-get-the-missing-dll-name-after-when-getlasterror-returns-error-mod-not#comment9324777_7661283).

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling LoadLibrary with a DLL name, shouldn't you already know the name?

You could always try [hooking](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) LoadLibrary if this isn't the case.

Comment: [s]he may not know the name if the missing dll is only a dependency of the one [s]he loads. nice idea *hooking*! one hopes for less extra work though. :)